# Why was my "obsolete" flag declined?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags

After having edited the question and created an appropriate answer I flagged the comment
["Don't give the solution in your own question"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445284/how-to-start-a-virtualbox-machine-via-command-line-without-gui#comment583408_445284) as "obsolete" - the answer part had been removed from the question.

This flag was declined, the comment is still there - was that a mistake or purposeful?

Comment: Dunno why the flag was declined nor why this got a downvote. I've removed the comment.

Comment: The comment was left by Avinash Raj, as an answer, so I declined it since it meant that that the answer was no longer needed.  Therefore; I convert it into a comment, since it wasn't an answer.

Comment: @Mitch, at the time my flag was declined there was one answer (community wiki) created from the OP's "answer" which I had extracted/removed. So the question really contained only the question. But nvm, I only wanted to understand if there was a reason I couldn't see.

Comment: If that's the case, then I apologize for making that mistake.

Comment: @Mitch no worries :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the comment, but I speculate that the comment was recently made and the OP (for whom the comment was made) might not have seen the comment by that time. Since the comment had some value that it tutored the OP on how the site works, it was obsolete but useful for the time being. So, one of the mods might have declined it for that reason.

Of course, this is all speculation from my side.